# Rails 3 file create getting permission denied error, using XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm working through Rails3inAction and cannot progress due to a permissions denied error.
The code is testing the processing of uploaded files through a separate files controller, relevant code is:

```
let(:asset) do
  ticket.assets.create(:asset => File.open(path))
end
```

When I run rspec, the error I'm getting is:

```
FilesController users without access cannot access assets in this project
 Failure/Error: ticket.assets.create(:asset => File.open(path))
 Errno::EACCES:
 Permission denied - C:/Documents and 
Settings/tick/public/system/assets/1/original/speed.txt
```

I suspect this is to do with windows XP and would appreciate any help!!

Comment: I have XP Home and it seems simple file sharing is enforced by default. I have NTFS partitions and therefore have no security tab.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a Rails problem, not a Permissions problem at all!